# Flutter_background_service: how to communicate between UI and background thread

Tags: flutter, flutter-plugin, flutter-packages, flutter-method-channel, flutter-background

The title says almost all - I'm not sure how to call *invoke* and *on* methods from the Flutter_background_service plugin, so that UI will be able to receive messages from the background and vice-versa? Any advice would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Since you don't really state your problem, it's hard to give much details.. but why don't you just look at the example of the plugin you've stated..

https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_background_service/example

on the UI just listen for the method you want the background thread to send using `on` method and subscribe to the stream. The above example uses that stream in a builder to update the UI:

```dart
            StreamBuilder<Map<String, dynamic>?>(
              stream: FlutterBackgroundService().on('update'),
              builder: (context, snapshot) {
                if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                  return const Center(
                    child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                  );
                }

                final data = snapshot.data!;
                String? device = data["device"];
                DateTime? date = DateTime.tryParse(data["current_date"]);
                return Column(
                  children: [
                    Text(device ?? 'Unknown'),
                    Text(date.toString()),
                  ],
                );
              },
            ),
```

On the background thread you would just use the `service` instance you get from the plugin and call the `invoke` methods on that method name you are listening to in the frontend, and pass in data..

also from that example..

```dart
    service.invoke(
      'update',
      {
        "current_date": DateTime.now().toIso8601String(),
        "device": device,
      },
    );
```